# Number of Sylow subgroups in $p$-solvable groups - paper of G. Navarro

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

This is a article which Gabriel Navarro wrote in 2003. I'm reading lemma 2.2. I see that

So we may assume that there is a proper normal subgroup N of $G$ such that $G/N$
is a $p$-group $\cdots $ divides $|N:H|=|G:M|.$

I don't understand why $|N:H|=|G:M|.$

https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-10/S0002-9939-03-06884-9/S0002-9939-03-06884-9.pdf

Comment: Please don't write in all-caps, as others might think you are shouting and being rude.

Comment: Wow, I sincerely thank you, this is the first time I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $K,L \leq G$, with gcd$(|G:K|,|G:L|)=1$, then $G=KL$ (try to prove this yourself!).

Since in the paper of Navarro, the Sylow $p$-subgroup $P \subseteq M$, we have $|G:M|$ is *not* divisible by $p$. And the $N \lhd G$ is chosen with $G/N$ to be a $p$-group. So, $G=MN$ and hence $|G:M|=|N:N \cap M|$. Navarro puts $H=N \cap M$.

**Note** The result of Navarro is very nice indeed and implies that for *solvable* groups $G$ the number $n_p(H)$ of Sylow $p$-subgroups of a subgroup $H$ with $p$ dividing $|H|$, divides the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups $n_p(G)$ of $G$. (A group is solvable iff it is $p$-solvable for every prime $p$). If you want to lift the $p$-solvability of $G$, then the result holds in case $H$ is *subnormal*. Without any condition, if $N \unlhd G$, then $n_p(G/N)$ divides $n_p(G)$. For a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814371/question-about-p-sylow-subgroups-of-the-quotient-group).

Here are some explanations for the proof of Lemma(2.2),we need some preparatory results, which are interesting in their own right.

**Proposition** Let $G$ be a finite group, $P \in Syl_p(G)$, and $N \unlhd G$. 
$(a)$ If $G/N$ is a $p$-group, then $N_G(P)/N_N(P)$ is a $p$-group.
$(b)$ If $G/N$ is a $p'$-group, then $N_G(P)/N_N(P)$ s a $p'$-group.

**Proof** note that since $N \unlhd G$, always $N \cap N_G(P)=N_N(P) \unlhd N_G(P)$. 
$(a)$ We have $P \subseteq N_G(P)$, whence $|G:N_G(P)|$ is not divisible by $p$. Hence gcd$(|G:N_G(P)|,|G:N|)=1$ yielding $G=NN_G(P)$. But then $|G:N|=|N_G(P):N_N(P)|$, being a power of $p$.
$(b)$ $G/N$ is a $p'$-group, so we must have $P \subseteq N$, whence $G=NN_G(P)$ by the Frattini argument. Again, $|G:N|=|N_G(P):N_N(P)|$ is a $p'$-group.

**Theorem** Let $G$ be a finite group, $P \in Syl_p(G)$, $N \unlhd G$ and $H \leq G$ with $P \subseteq H$. 
If $G/N$ is a $p$-*group* or a $p'$-*group*, then
$(a)$ $N_{HN}(P)=N_H(P)N_N(P)$
$(b)$ $|N_{HN}(P):N_H(P)|=|N_N(P):N_{H \cap N}(P)|$.

**Proof** Let us first assume that $G/N$ is a $p$-group. Since $P \subseteq H$, we have $P \subseteq N_H(P)$, whence $|N_{HN}(P):N_H(P)|$ is not divisible by $p$. By the Proposition $(a)$ $N_G(P)/N_N(P)$ is a $p$-group, so $|N_{HN}(P):N_N(P)|$ is a power of $p$. Hence gcd$(|N_{HN}(P):N_H(P)|,|N_{HN}(P):N_N(P)|)=1$ and $(a)$ follows.
$(b)$ This follows from $(a)$ and the fact that $N_H(P) \cap N_N(P)=H \cap N_G(P) \cap N \cap N_G(P)=H \cap N \cap N_G(P)=N_{H \cap N}(P)$.

Now, let $G/N$ be a $p'$-group, then $P \subseteq H \cap N \unlhd H$, so by the Frattini argument we have $H=(H \cap N)N_H(P)$, which implies $HN=NN_H(P)$. But then $N_{HN}(P)=HN \cap N_G(P)=NN_H(P) \cap N_G(P)=N_H(P)(N \cap N_G(P))=N_H(P)N_N(P)$, which is $(a)$. And $(b)$ follows by the same argument as above.

---

We are now ready to prove the statements at the end of the proof of Navarro's Lemma (2.2). Recall that the situation is as follows: $P \in Syl_p(G)$, $N \unlhd G$, even $P \cap N \unlhd G$, and so $P \cap N \in Syl_p(N)$ and $\overline{P}$ (the paper states $P$) acts coprimely (via conjugation) on $N/(P \cap N)$. We are given $P \subseteq M$. Note that since $G/N$ is a $p$-group, $PN/N=G/N$, so $G=PN=MN$.

$H=M \cap N$ and $\overline{H}=(M \cap N)/(N \cap P)=\overline{M} \cap \overline{N}$ is $\overline{P}$-invariant, since $\overline{P} \subseteq \overline{M}$ and $N$ is normal. Observe that $|G:M|=|MN:M|=|N:M \cap N|=|\overline{N}:\overline{H}|$$\text{    }(*)$.

To apply Lemma(2.1) (which is by the way Exercise 3E.4 in *Finite Group Theory*, I.M. Isaacs) we need to identify the $\overline{P}$-fixed points in $\overline{N}$, being $C_{\overline{N}}(\overline{P})$. It is not hard to see that this is the subgroup $\overline{N_G(P) \cap N}=\overline{C}$ in the notation of the paper.

Then owing to Lemma(2.1), we obtain: $|\overline{C}:\overline{C \cap H}|$ divides $|\overline{N}:\overline{H}|=|G:M|$ by formula $(*)$ above.

Finally, $$|\overline{C}:\overline{C \cap H}|=|(N_G(P) \cap N)/(P \cap N):(N_G(P) \cap N \cap M \cap N)/(P \cap N)| \\ =|N_G(P) \cap N:N_G(P) \cap M \cap N| \\ = |N_N(P):N_{M \cap N}(P)|= (\text{by Theorem (b) above}) \\ =|N_{MN}(P):N_M(P)|=|N_G(P):N_M(P)|.$$
This proves the Lemma(2.2).

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to ask this problem again. In the fourth line from the top of the second page, I don't understand this line "Hence, $G=(NM)\mathbf{N}_G(H)$." Maybe, $M\subset N.$ I'm not sure this.

Comment: Since $P \subseteq N \lhd G$, the Frattini argument gives $G=NN_G(P)$. But $N \subseteq NM$, so this guarantees that $G=(NM)N_G(P)$. If you have further questions contact me off-line (n.s.hekster@gmail.com).