Question about relations of Sylow $p$-subgroups in $G$ and $G/H$
I want to know if there's any theorem that relates how many sylow p-subgroups are in $G$ and $G/H$, where $H$ is a Sylow group. I "invented" a lemma that is somewhat useful, I leave it below with the proof I have come up with (even though I think it is not complete):
Lemma: Let $p,q$ be two different prime numbers. Let $G$ be a group with a normal Sylow $p$-group $N$. If the quotient group $G/N$ has exactly one Sylow $q$-group, then $G$ also has exactly one Sylow $q$-group.
Proof: Supose that $G$ has more than one Sylow $q$-group, so let $K$, $K'$ be two Sylow $q$-groups. Since $N$ is normal in $G$,the quotient $G/N$ is well defined (and it is also the only Sylow $p$-group in $G$ ), and we can construct the groups $KN$ and $K'N$ (by isomorphism theorems, these two groups are well constructed). Now consider the following group morphism:
$$
\pi:G \to G/N \\\ g \mapsto[g]
$$
Where $[g]$ is the equivalence class of $g$. Then:
$$
\pi(KN) = K_{\pi} \\
\pi(K'N) = K'_{\pi}
$$
Where $K_{\pi} = \{[k] | k \in K\}$. Now we have that $K_{\pi}$ and $K'_{\pi}$ are two different Sylow q-groups in $G/N$, but that cannot be since it contradicts the hypothesis that $G/N$ had only one Sylow $q$-group $\implies$ $G$ has only one Sylow $q$-group. $\square$
My questions are if this proof is corrected, if it can be strengthened, and if there are similar or better results relating the Sylow groups in $G$ and $G/N$.
EDIT
The previous result is false if $KN = K'N$, but I have derived another useful result from the previous "failed" lemma. Assume the same hypothesis as in the lemma. Given your unique Sylow $p$-group, call it N, and let's say There are $m$ Sylow $q$-groups in $G$, call them $K_i, \ (i \in \{ 1,2,...,m\})$. Then $K_iN = K_jN$ $\ (\forall i,j)$
Short proof: Supose $K_iN \neq K_jN$, then $\pi(K_iN) = K_{i\pi}$ and $\pi(K_jN) = K_{j\pi}$ $\implies K_{i\pi} = K_{j\pi} \implies K_iN = K_jN$ contradiction. If someone can check this and correct if it is worng I would really apreciate it.

When you write $\pi(KN)=K$, it's incorrect. $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, $\pi(KN)$ is a subgroup of $G/N$. So this key part of the argument is nonsense. You commit the same categorical error in your edit, claiming that subgroups of $G/N$ are equal to subgroups of $G$.

@ArturoMagidin I know i am suing kinda confusing notation, but the meaning is there. It mean the equivalence classes of the elements in K. Since K and N do not share any element, all elements of K have their own equivalence class (suppose [a] = [b] a,b in K, then exists n in N such that an = b implies n = a^-1b. Since a^-1b is in K, n is an element of K implying that K is the identity)-

"the meaning" is clearly "not there", given that you are drawing false conclusions. The image is $KN$, not $K$, and that is the key of your error.

@ArturoMagidin. $\pi(KN) = {\forall k \in K, [k] = kN }$ I called that K when in reality I should have used another name, like $K_{\pi}$. K and K_pi have the same cardinality

"${\forall k\in K, [k]=kN}$" is not a well formed formula. It is a nonsensical string of  symbols. By continuing to write nonsense, you continue to invite the drawing of false conclusions.

@ArturoMagidin I meant the group of the classes of equivalence of all elements in K. If K = {a,b} then $K_{\pi} = {[a],[b]}$. Maybe the correct way is ${[k] \ | k \in K}$. How would it be written correctly?

The latter is correct.

@ArturoMagidin then by making all these changes, are there any categorical errors?

If you correct all the errors, will it be correct? By definition, yes, but it is hard to say whether your only errors are nonsensical notation. At least on your pass they weren't. You'll have to fix things first before an assessment of what remains can be made.

@ArturoMagidin The only error I made was using wrong notation when assigning a symbol to $\pi(KN)$, and I think even though it is an error, it is still understandable. I am just a math student learning. I have fixed the confusion between K and K-pi. I already know that the initial lemma is incorrect by mathperson314 answer, I just want someone to verify if the answer is correct.

The correct statement is that if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then $G/N$ has a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup if and only if $N$ acts transitively by conjugation on the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

@DavidA.Craven can you provide a proof for your statement pls?

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814371/question-about-p-sylow-subgroups-of-the-quotient-group. $#Syl_p(G/H) \mid #Syl_p(G)$, for $H \unlhd G$.

The gap I can see in your proof is as follows: Why are $KN$ and $K'N$ distinct?
Consider $G = S_3 = \langle r, s \rangle$, the symmetric group on 3 elements generated by a 3-cycle $r$ and a 2-cycle $s$.
$|S_3| = 6 = 2 \cdot 3$ and $G$ has a normal Sylow 3-subgroup, $A_3 = \{1, r, r^2\}$.
$S_3$ has 3 subgroups of size 2, which are Sylow 2-subgroups. And yet $S_3/A_3 \simeq C_2$ is a cyclic subgroup of size 2, which has only one Sylow 2-subgroup (obviously).
Note that $K = \{1,s\}$ and $K' = \{1,rs\}$ are distinct Sylow 2-subgroups of $S_3$, but $KA_3 = K'A_3 = S_3$.

Using the language of your lemma, $p = 3, q = 2$. If you can show that, then the proof is valid.
